# Bestbuy Products Api show measures and weight of products?

Tags: best-buy-api

I've been looking for these attributes in the results but the API does not show it, is it a way to get measures and weight of items?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip: submitting an invalid field in your query will prompt the API to return an error message with a list of the possible fields you can search by and include in your results.

For example:

```
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(onfleek=*)?apiKey=<your_apikey>&format=json
```

You'll see from this that there are a variety of weight and dimension fields.  Here's a small sample of those fields:

```
productHeightIn
heightToTopOfDoorHingeIn
maximumStandHeightIn

weight
shippingWeight
```

These values are generally supplied by product vendors, so the meanings of the values and the units of measure can have a lot of variability in them.

The API does try to normalize some of the values. So when you see the field name postfixed with a unit of measure - those are fields that have been normalized.  For example "maximumStandHeightIn" means the unit of measure is "inches."

For many products, you can review the original vendor attribute values before normalization in the "details" field. Pass a "show=all" parameter in your query string to review the details field.

```
http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products?apiKey=<your_apikey>&format=json&show=all
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs I came up with this list of attributes obtainable from Products:

**weight**
*The weight attribute provides the weight of a product.*

Type
string
Notes
May return multiple weights like "Keyboard: 9.2 oz.; stand: 6.5 oz."
Related Attributes
height, depth, width
Example
"1.7 lbs."

**width**
*The width attribute provides the width of a product in inches.*

Type
string
Notes
May return multiple widths like "Subwoofer: 9.5"; satellites: 4.9" each"
Related Attributes
height, depth, weight
Example
"1.6" "